# Syncing Custom Color of the Line and the Legends with Data Loading from SQL for Multi-color Series

Tags: javascript, sql-server, highcharts

I have managed to plot a multi-color chart, but the legend is not syncing with the custom color of the lines. With this i need the Y axis minimum and maximum to be pulled from the query so it will be dynamic, also kindly help me in loading data_points dynamically from sql query for 3 different series along with the "color" and "segmentColor".

reference is https://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/1rv5jr65/1/

The data looks like the attached image:[image]

The Min-Max query:

```
select (select min(v) from (values (min(Actual)),(min([Prev Year])),(min([Plan]))) as value(v)) as Min_,
(select max(q) from (values (max(Actual)),(max([Prev Year])),(max([Plan]))) as value(q)) as Max_
from s5_test
```

The dataset query : `select * from s5_test`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it is possible to add small wrap in your code to allow you change color of your legendSymbol: http://jsfiddle.net/1rv5jr65/2/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thank you very much for your help.